# Ford Puma only blowing hot air

Tags: ford, heater-control

I recently had the clutch replaced on my car (well a friend did when I lent it to him). He replaced some other part he said was leaking - it looks very like the heater control valve when I google them on ebay (I think he is it was some water pump to my friend).

Anyway, it is now only blowing hot air. The mechanic is two hours away, so its a pain to back to get it checked. 
Assuming it is the heater control valve that was replaced, is there anything else I can check that might be causing it to blow hot air? Does it need any of the fluid levels topped up?

Update: I checked under the bonnet to look at the vacuum line as suggested, and noticed an electrical wire close to the window wipers that was unclipped. I need to find where it clips into now.

Comment: It could be that a vacuum line was not put back or was inadvertently disconnected to where now the heater control does not work. Not sure on your car if the heat is controlled with a valve (reduce the flow of fluid/heat through the heater core) or if it is controlled with a blend door which limits the amount of air which goes through the core. You might check these areas though.

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out I got conned by the mechanic. He knew I was in another town, so wouldn't get back to him.

I was told he had replaced the heater control valve, when in fact he had removed it and just put two plain tubes in its place.